# Change "Check out, review, and merge locally" steps

Tags: gitlab

since the last update of our self-hosted gitlab, the steps of the "Check out, review, and merge locally" pop-up have changed.

[image: new modifications]

They added the `origin/` just before the destination branch. But if you already have this branch localy, it will checkout on a commit hash, detached head style.

[image: detached head]

I know I can just delete the `origin/` part myself but i'm not the only one using it and people can get confused if they don't understand git enough.

Is there a way to modify instructions in these pop-up ? Make your own.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] To be clear, Can you, on Gitlab, change the text of the helping box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Gitlab v13, the text is now back to "normal"
The question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

in this case the origin means that the branch pink existed on the remote origin and since you checked out as origin/pink you checked out in he remote tracked branch.
You must checkout only with pink or shouldn't have use fetch.
I this case try git log and look at the tag you really want to checkout.

Comment: The fact is that I do want to checkout to the up-to-date pink branch.
The previous version of the Gitlab helping pop-up said : ``git checkout pink`` and it's exactly what i want.
My request is : Can we, anywhere on Gitlab, change the text in this box to lazily copy the whole commands.
(Sorry for not having be clear about that)